# Бархат - русизм чи таки літературне слово?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники, запозичені-слова, росіянізм

Часто натрапляю на різноманітні оголошення, зокрема і [тут](https://style24.prom.ua/p575279737-shikarne-barhatne-plattya.html) в яких написано саме слово "***бархат***". Думала, що це русизм. На підтвердження подаю [Тлумачний словник Ожегова](http://www.endic.ru/ozhegov/Barhat-1122.html).Однак, як виявилося, у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/barkhat) це слово фіксується:

> **БА́РХАТ**, у, чол. Те саме, що ***оксамит***. Дівчатка чинно розсілися спереду, поспиравшись на бильця, оббиті.. яскравим бірюзовим бархатом (Олександр Ільченко, Серце жде, 1939, 226)

Отже, слово "***бархат***" - русизм чи таки літературне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Літературне.

> Оксами́т  (давньорус. аксамитъ < дав.-гр. ἑξάμιτον)[1](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82), рідше
>   ба́рхат[2] (нім. Barchent)[3] — тканина з натурального шовку або
>   хімічного волокна з густим розрізним ворсом на лицьовому боці. Довжина
>   ворсу — звичайно 1—2 мм.

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82)

З вікістатті можна дізнатися, що слово походить від німецького Barchent, отже є швидше германізмом. Утім, вважати його запозиченим вже не можна, бо слово засвоєне давно і не сприймається як іншомовне.

Comment: Московизм не обовʼязково московське слова, може й чужомовне слово. Московська верхівка свого часу говорила німецькою та французькою. Зазвичай поверхньо перевірити можна так: порівняти з иншими словʼянськими мовами — як вони звучать та пишуть ся, бо навіть запозичені слова ріжнять ся. Німецькою, як бачу, взагалї [ˈbaʁçn̩t] ≈ _барх[е]нт_. Якщо збігає ся лиш з московською, дуже великий ризик, що московизм або вони запозичили в нас. Коли що, саме слово арабського першоджерела, в Західну Европу потрапило через латинь. Слово літературне, але менш вживане за _оксамит_ (навіть за словниками).